# How to use Dict[str, str] as a relationship property in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have a model that conceptually should just be a dictionary from one simple type to another for a parent. I've tried to implement custom collection class but it seems that it isn't the right approach, because a custom collection should take something of type `L1` as an argument when it adds it to collection. But the interface I want is `Root(children={'a': 'a'})`

```
class L1(Base):

__tablename__ = 'l1s'

id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
parent_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('roots.id'))
name = sa.Column(sa.String, unique=True)
value = sa.Column(sa.String)





class Root(Base):

__tablename__ = 'roots'

id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = sa.Column(sa.String, unique=True)
children = relationship('L1', backref='parent', collection_class=partial(AsSimpleDict, L1, 'name', 'value'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is the combination of a `collection_class` relationship and `association_proxy`.

```
class Parent(declarative.Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column("parent_id", Integer, primary_key=True)

    _config = relationship("Config",
                           collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('key'),
                           cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    config = association_proxy('_config', 'value',
                               creator=lambda k, v: Config(key=k, value=v))

class Config(declarative.Base):
    __tablename__ = 'config'

    id = Column("config_id", Integer, primary_key=True)

    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.parent_id'))
    playlist = relationship("Parent", back_populates="_config")
    key = Column(String)
    value = Column(String)
```

My understanding is that in this example, `_config` is effectively a `key -> Config object` dict, and that the association proxy takes this and presents it as a `key -> value` dict. Finally, the `creator` function turns `parent.config[key] = value` assignments into the creation of a `Config` object behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, did not new association_proxy can be used like that. Awesome!